# Foreign key constraing migration on Laravel 8 with syntax error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to execute some Laravel 8 Migatrions on MySQL 8.0.21 - MySQL Community Server, and trying to use some foreign key relationship, but the migration fails with

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")
```

The second error statement I receive is:

```
PDO::prepare("alter table `user_course` add constraint `user_course_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` ()")
```

The first table that will be used in the relationship migration it's the users table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
        $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The second one is the courses table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->tinyInteger('qnt_lessons');
        $table->smallInteger('qnt_hours');
        $table->string('link');
        $table->string('img')->nullable();
        $table->string('sell_link')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And the migration that fails is this one:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_course', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->reference('id')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
        $table->foreign('course_id')->reference('id')->on('courses');
        $table->tinyInteger('complete_lessons')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('completed');
        $table->date('due_date');
        $table->string('buy_platform');
        $table->string('buy_status', 32)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Schema::create('user_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {

rename in user_courses

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the syntax, you put reference and it's references here:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->reference('id')->on('users');
```

And here:

```
$table->foreign('course_id')->reference('id')->on('courses');
```

For example, your code would be as follows

```
$table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
```

I leave you the documentation of laravel so you can review

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Regards.

Comment: Thank you! It works too if I use foreignid() instead of foreign(), without the need to declare the column before.